Gatsby Image Cropping Behaviour
I'm using Gatsby and the gatsby-plugin-image to manage images being pulled in from a Netlify CMS. I'm struggling with the behaviour of the Gatsby Image plugin with Portrait images.
In particular, I have a full height hero image (sizes: "(min-width: 1024px) 1024px, 100vw") that has some strange cropping behaviour. It is happening all of the time, but its particularly obvious when the original image is portrait.
My header image original size is 2268px x 4032px. For some reason, Gatsby is cropping it to a landscape aspect ratio (1008 px x 568px). By doing this, I'm losing the key bits of the image - even with some intelligent cropping behaviour its not quite right. I don't understand what in my code is driving the cropping.
Here's the code in Gatsby for pulling in the image:
export const query = graphql`
  query ($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        author
        date(formatString: "MMMM YYYY")
        excerpt
        feature {
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(
                layout: CONSTRAINED
                placeholder: BLURRED
                formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
              )
            }
          }
          caption
          art_v
          art_h
        }
      ...
      }
    }
  }
`;


Try adding the height and width to the query:
export const query = graphql`
  query ($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        author
        date(formatString: "MMMM YYYY")
        excerpt
        feature {
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(
                height: 4032
                width: 2268
                layout: CONSTRAINED
                placeholder: BLURRED
                formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
              )
            }
          }
          caption
          art_v
          art_h
        }
      ...
      }
    }
  }
`;

